# How to select all rows from Kendo grid using checkbox on header

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, kendo-grid

I have select all checkbox on a Kendo Grid. This checkbox only selects first page and when you move to page to it is not selected. All I want is to use the checkbox to select all the rows from the grid. If the rows returned on the grid are 500, all of them must be selected by one click which is the checkbox. I have tried a lot of examples from but not getting it to work on MVC Razor.

I have tried many examples like this [Example](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/checkbox-selection-select-all-rows-all-pages)

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
                .Name("Grid")
                .ToolBar(toolBar => toolBar.Template("<strong><a className='k-grid-toolbar-create' onClick='goToFunctionDownloadAllIpossFile()' href ='" + Url.Action("GetFileFromSession", "ConsolidatedPOSS", "https") + "?SeletectOrders=#= SeletectOrders#'" + "><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'> Download Selected Orders </button></a></strong>"))
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                columns.Bound(x => x.ordernumber).Title("Order Number");
                 columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' id='chkId' #= selected ? checked='checked':'' # class='checkbox' />")
                .HeaderTemplate("<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox1' id='checkAll1' onclick='checkAll(this)'/>").Width(50);
                })
                .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                //.Refresh(true)
                .PageSizes(true)
                .ButtonCount(5))
                .Scrollable()
                .Filterable()
                .Sortable()
                .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(10)
                .ServerOperation(false)
                .Read(read => read.Action("Action", "Controller"))))
```

**Javascript**

```
function checkAll(ele) {
    alert();
    var state = $(ele).is(':checked');
    grid = $('#Grid').data('kendoGrid');

    datasource = grid.dataSource.view();
    //dataSource.pageSize(dataSource.total());
    $.each(grid.dataSource.view(), function ()
    {
        if (this['selected'] != state)
        {
            this.dirty = true;
        }  
        this['selected'] = state;
    });
    grid.refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this (an accordion example but you can make it relate to you):

```
 columns:[
        {
            field: "Checkbox", filterable: false, title: "<input type=\'checkbox\' class='\selectAll\' data-bind='checked:Checkbox' style='margin-left:3px;' />", width: "35px",
            template: '<input type="checkbox" style="margin-left: 4px;" class="checkone" # if (!CheckboxEnabled){ # disabled # } # # if (Checkbox){ # checked # } # />', sortable: false
        },
 ],

// set child checkbox values from parent checkbox
var setChildCheckboxes = function (parent) {
    var childCheckboxes = parent.closest('fieldset').find('.accordion-inner :checkbox');
    var activeChildCheckboxes = parent.closest('fieldset').find('.accordion-inner :checkbox:not(:disabled)');
    if (childCheckboxes.length > 0) {
        if (activeChildCheckboxes.length > 0) {
            var checkedValue = (parent.attr("checked") == "checked") ? true : false;
            activeChildCheckboxes.prop('checked', checkedValue);
        } else {
            // Uncheck and disable parent checkbox if there are no active child checkboxes
            parent.attr('checked', false);
            parent.attr('disabled', true);
        }
    }
};

// select all checkboxes
$('.checkall').on('click', function () {
    setChildCheckboxes($(this));
    // Enable/disable the action buttons
    if ($.find(':checkbox:checked').length > 0) {
        $("#push-button").attr("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $("#push-button").attr("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: How is hooked with the checkbox inside the grid in razor like what I have posted ?

Comment: i added the field column for you, does that help?

Comment: I am failing to understand on how it will work on kendo mvc Razor  as you can see my grid

Comment: Can you not use jquery at all?

Comment: Can you make a kendo dojo of your grid

Comment: How do i do that ?

Comment: Go to a kendo demo page and take out there code and insert yours ( use fake data ) I'll be able to look at this closer in 3 hours when I get to my computer

Comment: It seems like i cannot post in on kendo demo page since i don't have login details. can you please try it from your side? Thanks

Comment: I can, but make sure you click open in dojo and not the actual demo page

Comment: I just got in, i'll take a look at it now

Comment: Thanks, i will wait for your response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157998/discussion-between-keith-and-it-forward).